# How to define a balanced brace as parser rule instead of lexer rule

Tags: antlr

So I have the following grammar:

```
BalancedBrace:
   : '{'  (~('{' | '}') | BalancedBraces)*  '}'
   ;
```

It works well to parse text like this:

```
$sect {
  some stuff
  { nested braces are fine }
}
```

But now I need to allow some comment inserted to the text and it should be ignored in processing:

```
$sect {
  some stuff  # starting from the # to the end of line is ignored

  another stuff
  /# starting from the /# till #/ is ignored
  #/
}
```

So this means I need to change the balanced braces from lexer rule to parser rule, but I wonder what is the proper parser rule definition to allow nesting braces?

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the parser is very similar to what you have in the lexer rule:

```
sectionRule:
    '$sect' braceExpression
;

braceExpression:
    '{' braceContent '}'
;

bracContent:
    braceExpression
    | ... other content ...
;
```